# Safer and more efficient way to bulk insert data

Tags: laravel

I'm working on submitting data for an order. An order can have multiple items so I need to bulk insert. The data is sent from the front end as an array of objects with the `keys` being same as the column names of my table so I loop like this and save

```
$input = $request->all();
foreach ($input as $arr) {
     foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
          if (array_key_exists($key, $arr) && !empty($value)) {
               $data = array($arr);
           }
     }
     DB::table('orders')->insert($data);
}
```

`var_dump($input)` of the `request`

[image]

Is this efficient? Also I am currently requesting everything which seems unsafe. Is it possible to just request only certain keys like `prodName` and `prodDesc` instead of everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficiency in this case is superfluous as you're just receiving text and looping, at best it's a micro optimization. Also, we have no way of knowing what kind of performance detriments this loop may cause to you.

Next, the keys can be accessed in your loop, so if you only want those 2 keys, then build your $data from those 2 keys:

```
$data = [
    'prodDesc' => $arr['prodDesc'],
    'prodName' => $arr['prodName']
];
```

Of course add logic to make sure those specific keys exist, and raise errors if they don't or whatever.